# Write to disk with Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to write to disk in Parquet format using data from Spark Streaming.

I am getting slow write results using:

```
 val stream = ssc.receiverStream(...)

  stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>

    if (rdd.count() > 0) {

      // Get the singleton instance of SQLContext
      val sqlContext = SQLContext.getOrCreate(rdd.sparkContext)
      import sqlContext.implicits._

      // Save models in Parquet format.
      rdd.toDF()
        .write.mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .parquet("../myfile")
    }
  }
```

I compared this against reading the same data set once into memory and then once to disk with Spark, as opposed to the above, where a streaming approach is used.

Can anyone tell me why and give a solution?

Comment: What do you mean by poor write results?  What is your streaming interval?

Comment: @PatrickMcGloin I have tried 1 second to 20.  In every case it takes much longer to write than it would using a text file without Spark involvement.

Comment: Parquet is compressed so it should take longer to write than a text dump, or so I would think